# Regex language code in nginx location path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Hi I have these two block (working well)

```
location ^~ /beta/vi/static/ {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        alias /path/static/ ;
}

location ^~ /beta/en/static/ {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        alias /path/static/ ;
}
```

Can I merge them into 1 block, for catching vi and en ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a regex location (~*) for that:

```
location ~* ^/beta/(vi|en)/static/(.*)$ {
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    alias /path/static/$2;
}
```

You can add more to the list if necessary, like `(vi|en|bla)`.

Comment: Thanks, but it add a trailing slash at the end like this: beta/vi/static/assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js/

Comment: The alias directive has a different way of working with regex - I adjusted my answer, this should work now.